# Should I use history.js or HTML5 History API when trying to achieve back button functionally on a single page interface app

Tags: cordova, single-page-application, history.js, html5-history

So I've created a single page app using Phonegap and I'm using `divName.hide()` and `divName.show()` to switch between the app's pages. However, as expected, the back button of the phone (I'm using an Android phone) is not functioning as I would have wished, meaning it's exiting the app instead of going back to the previous state. 
So I searched about it and I came across with a few posts such as:
["Using the back button to revert to the previous state of the page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732378/using-the-back-button-to-revert-to-the-previous-state-of-the-page) 
and: ["Back Button for a Single Paged Website"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159853/back-button-for-a-single-paged-website), but after reading them all and the common tutorials on [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js), I can't decide which option will work better (or work at all) for an app built with Phonegap and running on android. 
Could you give me an advise on what is the better solution for my situation? Also, any additional guides and tutorials regarding this matter will be very helpful.

Comment: Hey, it's been over a day, any suggestions?

Comment: Still nothing I guess :-(

Comment: wondering.. which approach did you take?